# Flow Disjoint Unions with a default catch all

Tags: flowtype

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a disjoint union type with a catch all.
My idea if that if say the objects 'type' field is a certain value then I know I will have more data available.

I'm thinking it will look something like this:

```
type MyObject =
  | { type: 'extra_details', moreDetails: {here: 'it is'} }
  | { type: string }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chapter about Tagged unions in the docs.
https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#tagged-unions

But a check like

```
  function foo(x: MyObject) {
      if (x.type === 'extra_details') {
         // ...extra details code-path
      }
  }
```

is not sufficient to prove to flow that in this code-path, `x` can only be the extraDetails type. The check satisfies both types of the union. `{type: string}` is a more general case of `{type: 'extra_details'}`. You can can however check for the existence of the extra fields instead.

```
  if (x.moreDetails) {

  }
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that would be the case. Thanks!